# is it ok to save all of my data in one enormous table in parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm making an app and use parse.com as my backend, and I store the data in multiple tables, but I have some problems retrieving them, so I decided to save them all in one table.

my data contain images and PDF files.

is there any performance problem if I go that way when my app getting to grow?

Answer (score 1):

My guess there will be come a performance problem. It always will.

But why not focus on making the app a success?
Performance is only problem when it starts to become a problem.

Comment: "Performance is only problem when it starts to become a problem."
 but this is a dataBase and fixing it later will be very hard or impossible mission so I think it must be right from the beginning. 
but anyway thanks.